# Comment a file in Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a C header for which I want to write an introductory comment. Like this:

```
/**
 * @brief Provides stuff for my great program.
 */

#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

#define __USE_GLIBC

#endif
```

Furthermore, I have this Doxyfile:

```
FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES
TAB_SIZE = 8
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES
RECURSIVE = YES
INPUT = .
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
QUIET = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
```

When I run Doxygen now, it generates HTML and LaTeX documentation, but the brief description ends up documenting the macro instead of the whole file.

So how can I provide Doxygen with a brief description of the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `@file` macro to denote this comment related to the file as a whole:

```
/**
 * @file myheader.h
 * @brief Provides stuff for my great program.
 */
```

Comment: I finally did exactly this with a minor variation: I left out file file name after the `@file`, since I don’t like redundancy. It works nevertheless.

Answer (score 6):

While using `@file myfile.ext` works in any file (ie. not just the one where the documentation comment is), according to [the docs](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile), doing just `@file` will document the current file.

Complete example

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief A file that is documented.
 *
 * Detailed description, etc.
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your file is called `header.h`. Do this:

```
/*! @file header.h
 *  @brief Provides stuff for my great program.
 *
 *  Detailed description here, if any.
 */
```